# Wave file modification using java

Tags: java, audio, wave

I am currently trying to write a program in which i have to process a .wav file, i need to process the data in the wave file.

My main aim is to extract the data from currently existing file, create a new file with appropriate wave headers, and then write the information/data in the new file.

I am expecting the program to be written in java.

Comment: Interesting project. Do you have a question?

Comment: Do you have a problem, or are you just looking for pointers on how to get started?

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this in Google:

http://www.jstick.de/javaprojects/sampleeditor

This is a WAV editor and should provide you with the ideas for your implementation since it is open source.